# Why IF statement causes a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple piece of code like this :

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Change />, document.getElementById('app'));

function Change() {
    const [i, setI] = React.useState(0);
    let rnd = 9;
    if (i !== rnd) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setI(i + 1);
        }, 500);
    }
    React.useMemo(() => {
        console.log(i);
    }, [i]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>I change the state</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I don't understand why `if (i !== rnd)` Initiates a loop as the condition should just check the condition one time and move on with the code.

My thought process is like this :

1. `i` is 0 and is not equal 9 so it goes into the time out and waits for 500 ms
2. runs the increment and `i` becomes 1
3. `console.log` should show 1 being printed
4. end

Why does it become a loop and check whether `i` is equal to `rnd` or not as many as the `i` is not equal `rnd` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React works on a system of re-renders. When you change a variable that is used in your UI, Javascript doesn't know directly that you've changed it. That's why you have to use a state variable (`useState`) with a setter function and can't just declare a variable like you would in a backend setting. When something in the UI changes, React rerenders the entire component, so it effectively calls your function again.

When you use the state setter function `setI`, you are telling React to

1. Change the value of `i` AND
2. Rerender using the new value

So, stepping through your code here:

1. Initial render: `i = 0` and `rnd = 9`
2. `i !== rnd` is `true` since `0 !== 9`, the timeout is set
3. The component renders
4. The timeout expires, `i = i + 1`, rerender
5. Second render: `i = 1` and `rnd = 9`
6. `i !== rnd` is `true` since `1 !== 9`, the timeout is set
7. ...

So it's not that your if is causing a loop, it's that your function is being called multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're calling `setI` which will update the state and in turn re-render the component & the `if` condition?

Answer (score 2):

You're setting state in the setTimeout callback which triggers a re-render, which essentially is calling your `Change` function again with an incremented value of `i`. In that call the timeout gets set again, and then the state gets updated again which causes another re-render, and it goes on and on until i becomes equal 9.